# in eclipse, how to distinguish "run configurations" and "debug configurations" when adding self-define UI

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm a eclipse plugin developer. I have added a new tab in both "Run Configurations" and "Debug Configurations" (code is at one place for the two configurations). But I want to make a textbox invisible in "Run Configurations" and visible in "Debug Configurations". Right now, I have found one way: "parent.getShell().getText()" can return "Run Configuraions" or "Debug Configuratios" Strings for me. But are there any better ways to distinguish whether I'm in "Run Configurations" or "Debug Congurations"? The "getText()" way seems to be very not formal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the current 'mode' of the configuration represented by an id (and also by the `ILaunchMode` interface).

You can get the current mode id string from the `ILaunchConfigurationDialog` by calling the `getMode()` method. For debug the value will be the string defined by `ILaunchManager.DEBUG_STRING`.

In a launch configuration tab extending `AbstractLaunchConfigurationTab` you get the launch configuration dialog by calling `getLaunchConfigurationDialog`.